# Symfony2 Programmatically console command call does not work with namespaces

Tags: symfony, console, doctrine, command

I have a problem with execution of the Command in the Symfony2, mainly I have a command 'php app/console lets:do:this

which is executing the existing commands:

```
    $this->dumpToXml($input, $output);
    $this->dumpToAnnotation($input, $output);
    $this->dumpToEntity($input, $output);
```

But the second command 'dumpToAnnotation' fails. It indeed generates the php entity files but without the namespace (the namespace is included in the orm.xml files).

That is the method that fails:

```
private function dumpToAnnotation(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    // check if the command exists
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:mapping:convert');

    // collect all arguments and options
    $arguments = array(
        'command'      => 'doctrine:mapping:convert',
        'to-type'      => 'annotation',
        'dest-path'    => './src',
        '--force'      => true
    );

    // core objects
    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);

    // execute the command
    $command->run($input, $output);
}
```

It gives the output of **Processing entity 'Users'** instead of **Processing entity 'MyApp/MyBundle/Entity/Users**.

When I execute the command from the CLI, there is no problem at all, it's just does not work in the Command of Symfony2.

I hope someone can help me with that.

Regards, Greg.

Comment: not really, I have dropped the idea and I came out with different solution using command-line.